# Standard Margins for 6x9 Size Book

Tags: formatting, book, ebook, printing

I'm editing/formatting a book for a client and I've run into a bit of a technical issue--I've never formatted a book for print before and I can't seem to find the answer to the following question:

Are there standard margin sizes for specific book/page sizes?

The client has told me that the book should be formatted to be 6x9, but I've looked around different forums and it seems that everyone has their own preferred margins--is there no industry standard?

If not, what are some safe bets to go with? Also, will the margins for an ebook and a printed one differ? I would assume so do to the binding, but if they do, by how much?

A huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Find 10 or 20 6x9 books. Measure the margins with a ruler. Take the average or use the most common. Print out a few test pages and make sure they look good.

Answer (score 3):

When I was still in school I remember they had some outline for formatting books for our print department.

For 6x9 I believe it was 0.5" for headers and footers, 0.7" mirrored margin on the top, bottom and right side. The inside margin depends on the page count, I couldn't remember what they were off the top of my head but I was able to find the following:

> 24-150 pages, 0.375" inside margin
>   151-400 pages, 0.75" inside margin
>   400-600 pages, 0.875" inside margin
>   600+ pages, 1.0" inside margin

Doing some further research online, it looks like my school aligned with CreateSpace's guidelines: https://timctaylor.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/how-to-set-margins-microsoft-word-vs-createspace-vs-traditional-typesetting/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the kindle direct publishing format for a 6x9 paperback, I recommend using Apache open office 4. I put the page at user 6x9 and the margins at left and right .38 while the top and bottom are each.69 This is fitting perfectly for my manuscript. I hope this helps. Good luck and God bless.